# Flutter unwanted margin at top and bottom of the column

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a main page for my website using flutter,
I've put Columns with flexible widgets inside in it into the stack widget.
It looks fine and correctly positioned when in full screen, but when I change the size of the screen the columns won't stick to the top and displays a small margin in between.

Here are the codes

```
<sub>
class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MainPage> createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  bool _isLogin = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // check login
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
      if (isLogin()) {
        setState(() {
          _isLogin = true;
        });
      } else {
        MovePage(
            context: context,
            routeName: Routes.loginPage,
            generation: Generation());
      }
    });
    if (_isLogin) {
      return Scaffold(
        body: Stack(children: [
            const _OrangeVertical(),
            const _GreenVertical(),
            const _PurpleVertical(),
            const _LogoVertical(),
        ]),
      );
    } else {
      return const Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}

class _Logo1920 extends StatelessWidget {
  const _Logo1920();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const FlexibleImage(
      imgPath: 'assets/images/1920_logo.png',
      xFlexesOne: 3,
      xFlexesTwo: 4,
      xFlexesThree: 3,
      yFlexesOne: 325,
      yFlexesTwo: 625,
      yFlexesThree: 735,
    );
  }
}
class _Orange1920 extends StatelessWidget {
  const _Orange1920();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const FlexibleImage(
      imgPath: 'assets/images/1920_orange.png',
      xFlexesOne: 0,
      xFlexesTwo: 1,
      xFlexesThree: 2,
      yFlexesOne: 0,
      yFlexesTwo: 7,
      yFlexesThree: 10,
    );
  }
}

class _Green1920 extends StatelessWidget {
  const _Green1920();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const FlexibleImage(
      imgPath: 'assets/images/1920_green_new.png',
      xFlexesOne: 0,
      xFlexesTwo: 11,
      xFlexesThree: 20,
      yFlexesOne: 11,
      yFlexesTwo: 6,
      yFlexesThree: 0,
    );
  }
}

class _Purple1920 extends StatelessWidget {
  const _Purple1920();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const FlexibleImage(
        imgPath: 'assets/images/1920_purple.png',
        xFlexesOne: 20,
        xFlexesTwo: 11,
        xFlexesThree: 0,
        yFlexesOne: 0,
        yFlexesTwo: 0,
        yFlexesThree: 0);
  }
}

class FlexibleImage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String imgPath;
  final int xFlexesOne;
  final int xFlexesTwo;
  final int xFlexesThree;
  final int yFlexesOne;
  final int yFlexesTwo;
  final int yFlexesThree;

  const FlexibleImage({
    super.key,
    required this.imgPath,
    required this.xFlexesOne,
    required this.xFlexesTwo,
    required this.xFlexesThree,
    required this.yFlexesOne,
    required this.yFlexesTwo,
    required this.yFlexesThree,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        if (yFlexesOne > 0)
          Flexible(
            flex: yFlexesOne,
            fit: FlexFit.tight,
            child: const SizedBox(),
          ),
        Flexible(
          flex: yFlexesTwo,
          fit: FlexFit.tight,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              if (xFlexesOne > 0)
                Flexible(
                  flex: xFlexesOne,
                  fit: FlexFit.tight,
                  child: const SizedBox(),
                ),
              Flexible(
                flex: xFlexesTwo,
                fit: FlexFit.tight,
                child: Image.asset(
                  imgPath,
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
              ),
              if (xFlexesThree > 0)
                Flexible(
                  flex: xFlexesThree,
                  fit: FlexFit.tight,
                  child: const SizedBox(),
                ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        if (yFlexesThree > 0)
          Flexible(
            flex: yFlexesThree,
            fit: FlexFit.tight,
            child: const SizedBox(),
          ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
</sub>
```

and here are the screenshots

[normally it should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRoDi.png)
[but this happens when I change the size of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNCUu.png)

Initially this was happening for the row widget so I tried changing columns in rows to rows in columns, but now this happens

Comment: It won't solve your problem, but just so you know, a `Flexible` with `FlexFit.tight` is really the same as an `Expanded`. And a `Flexible` with `FlexFit.tight` and only a `SizedBox` as child is really identical to a `Spacer`. You could make cleaner code by using those

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this solution works. I think it's a bit of an ugly way to do it but I'm not sure if there's a better way. Replace

```
              Flexible(
                flex: xFlexesTwo,
                fit: FlexFit.tight,
                child: Image.asset(
                  imgPath,
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
              ),
```

with

```
              Flexible(
                flex: xFlexesTwo,
                fit: FlexFit.tight,
                child: LayoutBuilder(
                  builder: (context, constraints) {
                    return ConstrainedBox(
                      constraints: constraints.copyWith(minHeight: constraints.maxHeight != double.infinity ? constraints.maxHeight : constraints.minHeight),
                      child: Image.asset(
                        imgPath,
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                ),
              ),
```

The reason why it doesn't work without is when having rows in columns the children in the row will have their constrains as a set width but their height as a range between 0 and the available height. This solution makes it that it sees it as a fixed height.

I also think the purple one needs a `yFlexesTwo: 1`